# How to understand the action of nc -l

Tags: networking, nc

I've read the manual of `nc`, it tells me that `nc -l` means

> Used to specify that `nc` should listen for an incoming connection rather than initiate a connection to a remote host.  It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the `-p`, `-s`, or `-z` options. Additionally, any timeouts specified with the `-w` option are ignored.

As my understanding, the action of `nc -l` looks like a server. For example, on the same server, one terminal with `nc -l 9000` will listen on the port 9000. The other terminal with `nc localhost 9000` will become a client. So I can send messages from the second terminal to the first terminal.

However, today I'm learning the Apache Flink. Here is the Hello World of Flink: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/getting-started/tutorials/local_setup.html

```
$ nc -l 9000
lorem ipsum
ipsum ipsum ipsum
bye
```

It seems that the action of `nc -l` here is a kind of sending messages, instead of listening on the port.

I'm confused now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being the target of an incoming connection doesn't prevent netcat from sending data. Once a client has connected, it can both send data to and receive data from the client. In this case, it's sending data to the Flink client.

Answer (score 3):

`nc -l 9000` in the example acts like a server.  The Flink application connects to this server and waits for input.  Note that Flink is started after running the `nc` command.

Now they are connected. You type some words into `nc` and the Flink application responds (by writing to an output file).

The fact that you use `nc -l` to send data to the application may feel a bit backwards, but there's nothing stopping `nc` and Flink from communicating in this way.

Answer (score 0):

`nc -l <port>`
certainly opens up a `<port>` and listens for connections

### The procedure can be validated by following the below steps

**Step 1:** Open a terminal and listen on it by doing `nc -l 32000`

**Step 2:** Open another terminal and connect to the open port by `telnet localhost 32000`

**Step 2a:** Type strings in either of the terminal and they'd be sent to the listener on other terminal.

---

Also, running a netstat after `nc -l 32000` will show the staus of the connection as a listener

`netstat -atn | grep 32000
tcp4       0      0  *.32000                *.*                    LISTEN`